# Focusing the perspective on the avatar when it moves around is not working in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am exploring Three JS. I am a beginner to 3D programming. I am following a tutorial in this book, https://canvas.projekti.info/ebooks/3D%20Game%20Programming%20for%20Kids.pdf. Basically, the game is controlling an avatar moving around the trees. What I am doing now is that I am trying to get the camera to always focus on the back of the avatar as it moves around in the 3D space.

I have created a marker for that. Marker is attached to the avatar. Then the camera is focusing on the marker. But when I move the avatar, the camera is not moving along with the camera.

This is my code:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 500;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// **************** start coding here *********************
var marker = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(marker);

var cover = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var body = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100);
var avatar = new THREE.Mesh(body, cover);
marker.add(avatar);

var hand = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50);
var rightHand = new THREE.Mesh(hand, cover);
rightHand.position.set(-150, 0, 0);
avatar.add(rightHand);

var leftHand = new THREE.Mesh(hand, cover);
leftHand.position.set(150, 0, 0);
avatar.add(leftHand);

var feet = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50);
rightFeet = new THREE.Mesh(feet, cover);
rightFeet.position.set(-75, -125, 0);
avatar.add(rightFeet);

leftFeet = new THREE.Mesh(feet, cover);
leftFeet.position.set(75, -125, 0);
avatar.add(leftFeet);

marker.add(camera);// Focus the camera on the marker.

function makeTreeAt(x, z) {
    var trunk = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.CylinderGeometry(50, 50, 200),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xA0522D })
    )

    var top = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(150),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x228B22 })
    )
    top.position.y = 175;
    trunk.add(top);

    trunk.position.set(x, -75, z);
    scene.add(trunk);
}

makeTreeAt(500, 0);
makeTreeAt(-500, 0);
makeTreeAt(750, -1000);
makeTreeAt(-750, -1000);

var isCartWheeling = false;
var isFlipping = false;
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    if (isCartWheeling) {
        avatar.rotation.z = avatar.rotation.z + 0.05;
    }
    if (isFlipping) {
        avatar.rotation.x = avatar.rotation.x + 0.05;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    var code = event.keyCode;
    if (code ==  37) avatar.position.x = avatar.position.x - 5; // move left
    if (code == 38) avatar.position.z = avatar.position.z - 5; // up - move forward
    if (code == 39) avatar.position.x = avatar.position.x + 5; // move right
    if (code == 40) avatar.position.z = avatar.position.z + 5; // down - move backward

    if (code == 67) isCartWheeling = ! isCartWheeling; // C
    if (code == 70) isFlipping = ! isFlipping; // F
});
animate();
```

```css
            body {
                margin: 0px;
            }
            canvas {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>First 3D avatar game</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r125/three.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to be careful with your object nesting. This is what you have now

```
Marker
├── Avatar
└── Camera
```

You have Avatar and Camera as children of Marker, but you're only updating the position of Avatar, so Marker remains unmoved, and the camera won't follow.

Instead of updating the position of Avatar, if you want the camera to follow, you'll have to update the position of Marker, so both its children get moved in sync, like in the demo below:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 500;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// **************** start coding here *********************
var marker = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(marker);

var cover = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var body = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100);
var avatar = new THREE.Mesh(body, cover);
marker.add(avatar);

var hand = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50);
var rightHand = new THREE.Mesh(hand, cover);
rightHand.position.set(-150, 0, 0);
avatar.add(rightHand);

var leftHand = new THREE.Mesh(hand, cover);
leftHand.position.set(150, 0, 0);
avatar.add(leftHand);

var feet = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50);
rightFeet = new THREE.Mesh(feet, cover);
rightFeet.position.set(-75, -125, 0);
avatar.add(rightFeet);

leftFeet = new THREE.Mesh(feet, cover);
leftFeet.position.set(75, -125, 0);
avatar.add(leftFeet);

marker.add(camera);// Focus the camera on the marker.

function makeTreeAt(x, z) {
    var trunk = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.CylinderGeometry(50, 50, 200),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xA0522D })
    )

    var top = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(150),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x228B22 })
    )
    top.position.y = 175;
    trunk.add(top);

    trunk.position.set(x, -75, z);
    scene.add(trunk);
}

makeTreeAt(500, 0);
makeTreeAt(-500, 0);
makeTreeAt(750, -1000);
makeTreeAt(-750, -1000);

var isCartWheeling = false;
var isFlipping = false;
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    if (isCartWheeling) {
        marker.rotation.z = marker.rotation.z + 0.05;
    }
    if (isFlipping) {
        marker.rotation.x = marker.rotation.x + 0.05;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    var code = event.keyCode;
    if (code ==  37) marker.position.x = marker.position.x - 5; // move left
    if (code == 38) marker.position.z = marker.position.z - 5; // up - move forward
    if (code == 39) marker.position.x = marker.position.x + 5; // move right
    if (code == 40) marker.position.z = marker.position.z + 5; // down - move backward

    if (code == 67) isCartWheeling = ! isCartWheeling; // C
    if (code == 70) isFlipping = ! isFlipping; // F
});
animate();
```

```css
body {
                margin: 0px;
            }
            canvas {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>First 3D avatar game</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r125/three.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```